# Want to create dynamic method for calling procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

My aspx.cs calling

```
protected void btnState_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
param.Direction
param[0].ParameterName = "@state";
param[0].Value = txtState.Text;
obj.insrtsp("SpInsertState", param);
}
```

*Method in Class file as my input*

```
public void insrtsp(string str, SqlParameter[] param )
{
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = cn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = str;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

}
```

Right now I am using stored procedure in a way that every time I have to type whole things while executing it but I want to create a dynamic method for stored procedure by which I can just create object of that method and call procedure by passing arguments.

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Does anyone having solution please.???

Comment: U can create saperate class for that... Like `DAL` , `BAL` and `Property` for that...

Comment: How about `Cmd.CommandText = "EXEC sp_StoredProc val1, val2, val3, val4";`?

Comment: where are you using `SqlParameter[] param `??